# Protecting all admin/ routes with auth in Laravel

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-3

I am brand new to laravel and am setting up admin panel authorization on my first application. The way I have my files setup currently setup is:

```
controllers/
    admin/
        dashboard.php
        settings.php
    non-admin-controller1.php
    non-admin-controller1.php
views/
    admin/
        dashboard.blade.php
        login.blade.php
        template.blade.php
    non-admin-view1.php
    non-admin-view1.php
    non-admin-view1.php
```

...and these are my routes

```
Route::get('admin/login', function()
{
    return View::make('admin.login');
});

Route::get('admin/logout', function()
{
    return Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::to('admin/login');
});

Route::post('admin/login', function()
{
    $userdata = array('username' => Input::get('username'),
                      'password' => Input::get('password'));
    
    if (Auth::attempt($userdata))
    {
        return Redirect::to('admin');
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('admin/login')->with('login_errors',true);
    }
});

Route::controller('admin.dashboard');

Route::get('admin', array('before' => 'auth', function() {
    return Redirect::to_action('admin@dashboard');
}));

Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::to('admin/login');
});
```

When I go to /admin I am redirected to admin/login and asked to login which is exactly how I need it to work. Upon logging in I am redirected to admin/dashboard and it all looks good there too. I am having 2 problems however.

1. When I go to admin/logout I am logged out but greeted with a blank page (it's not redirecting to admin/login)
2. When logged out, if I go to admin/dashboard I am greeted with the error

> Error rendering view: [admin.dashboard]
>
> Trying to get property of non-object

What am I doing wrong here? What am I doing right? Would it make more sense to create a separate bundle for admin? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I was able to solve my problem a slightly different way. I created an (base) Admin_Controller in the root of the controllers folder, with a constructor calling the auth filter before execution:

```
class Admin_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->filter('before', 'auth');
    }

}
```

and then made all my admin related controllers in /controllers/admin extend Admin_Controller and call the parent constructor:

```
class Admin_Dashboard_Controller extends Admin_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function action_index()
    {
        return View::make('admin.dashboard');
    }

}
```

This might not be the most eloquent solution, but it does the job!

Answer (score 9):

In your `admin/login` route you have an unnecessary return before the `Auth::logout()` call, nuke that and it should fix it up.

Another issue here is that only your one 'admin' route is getting filtered. You could wrap all of your admin routes with a `Route::group()` and apply the 'auth' before filter or you could use `Route::filter('pattern: admin/*', 'auth')` too.

Check out:

http://laravel.com/docs/routing#filters

For the second issue, is your Admin Dashboard controller class named `Admin_Dashboard_Controller` and if so, do you have an action_index() or get_index() function in there returning a view?

Check out:

http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#nested-controllers

(I'm assuming you're using L3 here btw.)

Comment: Thank you @Darren Monahan for your answer! Yes, I am using L3.

Are you reffering to
`Route::get('admin/login', function()
{
    return View::make('admin.login');
});` ? I tried removing it and am met with a 404 error as I don't currently have an admin class with login method.

I tried `Route::filter('pattern: admin/*', 'auth')` but got stuck in a redirect loop.

I have an Admin_Dashboard_Controller that looks like this 
`class Admin_Dashboard_Controller extends Base_Controller {

 public function action_index()
 {
  return View::make('admin.dashboard')->with('menu_active','dashboard');
 }

}`

Comment: Please ignore the first part of my comment, I figured out what you meant and fixed it: `return Auth::logout();` :)

Comment: I tried Route::filter('pattern: admin/*', 'auth') but got stuck in a redirect loop.

Looks like the Filter is being called before the Base controller construct method. So, I can't do the exception for the login index page.

Answer (score 8):

For future readers, a very clean way to handle this is using Laravel's [Route Groups](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-groups):

> Route groups allow you to share route attributes, such as middleware or namespaces, across a large number of routes without needing to define those attributes on each individual route.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ()    {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });

    Route::get('user/profile', function () {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });
});
```

They can be used not only for authentication, but also `Namespaces`, `Sub-Domains`, and more.