# Laravel 4 - Improve code to check for Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing, code-cleanup

I have a Laravel 4 application with a resource Poll

```
// routes.php
Route::resource('polls', 'PollController');
```

I do not want anyone to be able to list all the polls, except if the user is authenticated and if (s)he is an admin. This was my solution:

```
// PollController.php
public function index() {

    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->admin) {
        return View::make('polls.index', Poll::all());
    }

    return View::make('polls.create', []);
}
```

This code works just fine, but it is not very [clean](https://vimeo.com/12643301) [code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc). For once, I make this the "admin check" in a few places. Also it does not feel like it follows the practice of "A function should be doing just 1 thing".

I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to handle cases where the response changes depending on whether the user is logged in and is an admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Route Groups and Auth Filters.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-groups

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#protecting-routes

#### Example

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
  // Route::resource('poll', 'PollController');
  // Additional routes
}
```

Here is a great tutorial series on Laravel in general (and your topic);
http://culttt.com/2013/09/16/use-laravel-4-filters/

Comment: `Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{ // add all your resources here });`

Comment: Why would you comment on your own answer? Just edit ;)

Comment: @Kyslik there was a question there previously... "How would I add a filter to a Route::resource"

Comment: Either way good practise is to edit your answer. Exactly for this reason. ###Example past it there and done.

Comment: That would add the filter to all the routes of the resource. I just wanted it for the "index" route. But this solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823161/protecting-all-admin-routes-with-auth-in-laravel